# Whenever i use random.choice in Python, i get an error. The error is in the 'body' page

Tags: python, random, compiler-errors

```
playsound.playsound(random.choice(beatboxes))
```

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'

Process finished with exit code 1

there is an alternative to the bultin random module?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bad import. Show us the related import line(s)!

Comment: @KlausD.yeah...here it is..  from random import *

Comment: Then it is just `choice` w/o `random.`. Please note that the use of wildcard imports is discouraged. See PEP 8 for details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use random with a choice like you write in code you need to import

```py
import random
```

Here In your case

```py
from random import *
```

will now work